# protobuf message containing fields which are protobuf messages marshaling and unmarshaling

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message which is similar to message a below.

```
message a {
    message b xyz = 1; //message a basically is defined using message b here.
}
message b {
    int age = 1;
}
```

Now, when sending message of type a, I want to know if I need to marshal message b first, then marshal a - similarly unmarshal msg (type a) followed by unmarshal of xyz(type b) to get data?

I didn't find anything about it in protobuf documentation, so maybe this is not required. wondering if a simple marshal (type a) and unmarshal (type a) is sufficient.

Comment: Just worry about the top level message. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#other

Comment: @CaptainMurphy thanks